# Why does the variable not live long enough?

Tags: rust, object-lifetime, lifetime

Consider this function that should return the file extension of a given `Path`.

```rust
pub fn get_extension<'a>(path: &'a Path) -> Option<&'a str> {
    let path_str = path.as_str().unwrap();
    let ext_pos = regex!(".[a-z0-9]+$").find(path_str);

    match ext_pos {
        Some((start, _)) => {
            return Some(path_str.as_slice().slice_from(start))
        },
        None => return None
    }
}
```

The error message is as follows:

```
`path_str` does not live long enough
```

[image]

The error message is pretty clear and it's a shame I can't work it out on my own. I understand it in theory but there are still a couple of blurred things for me.

I understand that the compiler wants to tell me that `path_str` does not live long enough to be valid as the return value with is marked with lifetime `'a`.

But this is where it stops for me:

- I understand that the reference to `path` (the input parameter) should life exactly as long as the reference to the `str` that is wrapped in the `Option` (the output parameter)
- since we return `Some(path_str.as_slice().slice_from(start))` I assume that in practice that means that `path_str` needs to live as long as `path`.

What I don't understand is **why exactly** does `path_str` not live long enough and how could I fix this? What makes it die to soon?

**UPDATE**

As pointed out in the comments and also on IRC removing the superflous `as_slice()` makes the code compile. Does anyone know why that is? It was also pointed out that there exists a [method](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/path/trait.GenericPath.html#method.extension) to get the extension directly. But yep, I'm actually more interested in learning the story behind the problem though.

Comment: Path_str is already a slice so you can remove that as_slice and it will work. This is probably a bug.

Comment: Thanks. That did the trick. I update the question accordingly.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This isn't a bug. The "problem" here is [`as_slice`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/master/std/str/trait.Str.html#tymethod.as_slice)'s definition. It takes a reference to its arguments, and returns a `&str` with the same lifetime as the *reference*, it can't introspect into the internal lifetimes of whatever type it is being called on. That is, `path_str.as_slice()` returns a `&str` that lasts for as long as `path_str`, *not* as long as the data `path_str` points at (the original `Path`).

In other words, there's two lifetimes here. I'll use a hypothetical block-lifetime annotation syntax on the example from @Arjan's [filed bug](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/15357) (this answer is based of [my response there](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/15357#issuecomment-47852104)).

```
fn test<'a>(s: &'a String) -> &'a str {
    'b: {
        let slice: &'a str = s.as_slice();
        slice.as_slice()
    }
}
```

For the second `as_slice` call we have `self: &'b &'a str`, and thus it returns `&'b str`, which is too short: `'b` is just local to `test`.

---

As you discovered, the fix now is just removing the extraneous `as_slice` call. However, with [dynamically sized types (DST)](http://smallcultfollowing.com/babysteps/blog/2014/01/05/dst-take-5/), we will be able to write `impl StrSlice for str`, and then `slice.as_slice()` *will* be returning a `&'a str`, since there won't be an extra layer of references (that is, `self: &'a str`).

Comment: So with this equivakent definition of Str trait: http://is.gd/L4yATO, how is that type signature not a lie?

Comment: @Arjan Which type signature? `fn as_slice2<'a>(&'a self) -> &'a str`?

Comment: yes, its claiming its reyurning something with lifetime 'a but *self is of lifetime 'b. Or does it infer that 'a < 'b an this makes it valid?

Comment: @Arjan Yes, `&'b self` says `self` points to data that is completely valid for at least `'b`, which means the `&'a str` must be valid for at least that long, so `'b < 'a`.

Comment: But it can't infer that 'a == 'b?

Comment: Yes, because it's not true, as this question demonstrates. (In my answer `slice`, i.e. `'b` (when the reference is taken), doesn't live as long as the data it points to, i.e. `'a`.)

Comment: Oh, right. *self if actually of lifetime 'a but compiler can't know that because in this context it is already assigned the lifetime 'b.

Comment: It demonstrates how references work in practice. The spot where you make a reference -- in this case where you call the method it makes a `&self` -- is the "anchoring point" of that reference.