# The lifetime of &str makes comparison hard

Tags: string, rust

I want to play with BasicAuth stuff, therefore I need the base64 version of a string. So I needed a function : String to base_64(String).

In the string guides for Rust, most of the time $str is preferred to String. So I wanted to adjust to this idea.

But working with &str is somehow harder than it seems (I know that my problem is related to [Question also about as_slice()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24542064/why-does-the-variable-not-live-long-enough)).

The author of other question could solve his problem by not using as_slice(), is there a way to still work with &str for me?

```
extern crate serialize;

use serialize::base64::{ToBase64,MIME};

fn generate_base_string (n : &str) -> String {
    let mut config     = serialize::base64::MIME;
    config.line_length = None;
    let bytes: & [u8]  = n.as_bytes();
    return bytes.to_base64(config);
}

fn generate_base<'a> (n : &'a str ) -> &'a str {
    let mut config     = serialize::base64::MIME;
    config.line_length = None;
    let bytes: & [u8]  = n.as_bytes();
    let res2:  String  = bytes.to_base64(config);
    let res1: &'a str  = res2.as_slice();
    return res1;
}

#[test]
fn right_base64() {
    let trig :&str = generate_base("string");
    assert!(trig=="c3RyaW5n");
}
// http://doc.rust-lang.org/guide-strings.html
#[test]
fn right_base64_string(){
    // A `String` - a heap-allocated string
    assert!(generate_base_string("string")=="c3RyaW5n".to_string());
}
```

These are my first baby steps in Rust so please be not to mean if I do something really wrong.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`&` is a *pointer*, it points to a memory that somebody else owns.
So, `&str` is a pointer to a string memory (slice) that somebody else owns.
`String`, on the other hand, is a string that owns its memory and keeps the characters there.

Now, when you generate a base64 you make something new, it's like hearing a piano concerto and catching it in an oil painting. Instead of taking your brush and making the painted version of the concerto you could just *point* to the original music, but that won't work when you specifically need a painted version. Similarly simply *pointing* to the original string won't work when you need a base64 version. You need to make something new, you need a canvas for it, that is the `String`.

What you're trying to do in `fn generate_base<'a> (n : &'a str ) -> &'a str` is akin to creating a painting, destroying it and pointing to the destroyed painting. Look at the painting I made!.. only I've burned it. That's against the Rust safety rules, you shouldn't point to something which no longer exists (it's also known as a "[dangling pointer](http://doc.rust-lang.org/reference.html#behavior-considered-unsafe)").

`String` is not evil, don't be afraid to use a new `String` when you're creating something new.

---

But why people avoid `String`? It's because passing `String` is like passing the real painting. Imagine a museum taking the Leonardo from the wall and giving it to you: here, take it for a walk, enjoy. Now that you've taken it, nobody else will see it in the museum. And you'll have to give it back. It's often easier to simply visit the museum and look at the thing, without moving it anywhere.

Comment: thank you :) Sometimes it needs someone else to make it click

Comment: You're welcome! ) I think it's actually more intuitive than in the languages with a different semantics.

Comment: That's a brilliant way of illustrating this, bravo!