# How do I return a reversed string from a function?

Tags: rust, lifetime

I want to write a function that would reverse a string and return a reference to the returned string. I thought I would be able to specify that the returned reference has the same lifetime as the provided reference.

```
fn reverse_string<'a>(input: &'a str) -> &'a str {
    let res: &'a str = input.chars().rev().collect().as_slice();
    res
}
```

This was my attempt, and I receive the error:

```
error[E0282]: type annotations needed
 --> src/lib.rs:2:24
  |
2 |     let res: &'a str = input.chars().rev().collect().as_slice();
  |                        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ cannot infer type for `B`
  |
  = note: type must be known at this point
```

I thought the type specification would resolve this. Lifetimes are a bit confusing to me, so I was hoping someone may be able to explain how to do this properly, or if I'm completely off base to begin with.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The lifetime issue is similar to [The lifetime of &str makes comparison hard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26913532/the-lifetime-of-str-makes-comparison-hard): if you create a *new* object, it's a new object, uncorrelated from the old one.

Therefore, you have two choices:

- either create a completely new object: `input.chars().rev().collect()` for example
- or reverse the `input` *in-place*, which requires it to be `mut` of course

The former *looks* easy:

```
fn reverse_new(input: &str) -> String {
    input.chars().rev().collect()
}
```

however the `String` so created might be "flawed", because `char` (the intermediate type) are just Unicode code points not graphemes. As an example of [Combining Characters](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combining_character) imagine that you have [`e`, `́`, `o`] in the original string, the `́` is attached to the `e`: `éo`, but after reversal you get  [`o`, `́`, `e`] where `́` is attached to the `o`: `óe`.

The latter is severely complicated by the fact that even ignoring graphemes issues, reversing UTF-8 in-place requires being UTF-8 aware to avoid splitting codepoints. Of course, one could simply create a reversed `String` and copy it into the input...

**EDIT:** I had initially thought of collecting into an intermediary `Vec`, but @AlexP realized it was unnecessary and one could collect directly into a `String`.

Comment: Thanks for the help! However, when trying to compile the above snippet, using rust 0.12.0-dev, I receive the error "the type of this value needs to be known in this context," with the portion "v.as_slice()" indicated.

Comment: (Whoops, missed edit window) And I was wondering what the lifetime of the returned reference would be? I'm not actually sure how returning references works with regards to borrowing, etc., and I couldn't find anything on it in the documentation.

Comment: @AlexP: You cannot return a reference from a function if the referent was created in the function, because the value would be destroyed when the function exits and the reference would be dangling. By returning a `String`, you return a value that owns the string's contents, so there is no borrowing involved.

Comment: Thanks @FrancisGagné, really appreciate the help. :) Managed to iron out my problems.

Comment: @AlexP: Did you need an annotation for `collect` ? If required, you can use either `let v: Vec<char> = ...;` or `collect::<Vec<char>>()`.

Comment: @MatthieuM. This was the final function I ended up using. It seems to work as I need it, but please let me know if anything is wrong with it that I should be aware of.

fn reverse_string(input: &str) -> String {
    input.chars().rev().collect()
}

Comment: @AlexP: Ah nice, even better than using a temporary vector! The only flaw, as I mentioned, is that Unicode contains [Combining Characters](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combining_character). So if you have `e` followed by ` ́` followed by `o` in the original string, the ` ́` is attached to the `e`: `éo`, but after reversal it is attached to the `o`: `óe`.

Answer (score 0):

The function that ended up functioning as intended:

```
fn reverse_string(input: &str) -> String {
    input.chars().rev().collect()
}
```